# Where do I ask my opinion-based question?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to ask a definitely opinion-based question about the codility service (namely: "How difficult are the codility tasks in your opinion?") but I know it's against the rules of SO.

The reason I wanted to ask it here and not somewhere else that this site gathers thousands (if not millions?) of programmers from around the world, has a very high traffic and people coming here expect others to ask them questions so simply on this site I would get a lot of answers and fast.

The other reason is... I simply don't know where else I could ask it. Is there any other programming Q&A site that would allow my question? If not, is there any internet forum or other site focused around programming that is very popular and could accommodate my question?

Comment: Just one example. This sort of thing has been asked repeatedly.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Answer to the question you linked only says that a fitting place would be a forum (which I already know) but fails to provide ANY examples. Im asking "where can I put my specific question" and I would like to get some example sites as an answer.

Comment: @NPS Questions on Meta are supposed to be about Stack Overflow or at least Stack Exchange in general. We can help answer if you're asking whether there's a place within the Stack Exchange network, but if you're looking for places outside of the Stack Exchange network, I'm pretty sure that's off-topic.

Comment: Search engines do links.  In this case, who cares what other people's opinions are about the difficulty.  Go forth, create a prototype, find out how hard it is for you to work with it.  That's the optimal answer for such questions, because it lets you know how hard it is for **you** to work with it, not some random guy on the internets.

Comment: @Will I **already know** how hard it is to me. I want to ask that question specifically to find out others feel about it so I have some sort of reference.

Comment: Aaand what would you do with that information?

Comment: @Will Clearly, you think I shouldn't care what others think and that they're opinion is unrelevant. Exactly clearly, **you're wrong**. But I'm not gonna waste time trying to explain it to you. You're free to ignore this thread since you're not going to help in any way.

Comment: Nah, I'm right.  Prototype it and judge for yourself.  But keep on thinking other people's opinions are important to your development.  Oh, I mean other people's opinions, ***but not mine*** (bold + italics, so I beat you).